# Using a variable in an if/for/do-while block in php

Tags: php, variables

If I am not wrong I used to use a new PHP variable in an if statement or a conditional loop block for the first time. What I want to say is like the following.

```
<?php

    for($i=0;$i<10; $i++)
    {
        $total += $i;
        $concat .= $i;
    }
 ?>
```

But today, when I look at the error logs, it says $total and $concat are undefined variables. Then I write this

```
    $total = 0;
    $concat="";   
    for($i=0;$i<10; $i++)
    {
        $total += $i;
        $concat .= $i;
    }
 ?>
```

It works with no error. Why?
Asking just for curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

It is because:

```
$total += $i;
$concat .= $i;
```

actually means:

```
$total  = $total+$i;
$concat = $concat.$i;
```

The first time you execute the loop, `$total` and `$concat` are undefined. So you get the error.

**More details:**

During the first run of the loop, you are writing

```
$total = the value of undefined $total + $i;
```

now, total is defined. Same for $concat.

Comment: this is not what i want to know.

Comment: @OzkanOzlu it's what you asked.

Comment: I said, I used to use the first code above with no error. But today i cannot. What i asked is why not today?

Comment: @OzkanOzlu You asked why the error does not show up when you define the vars before executing the loop. I did answer your question.

Comment: @OzkanOzlu It is because today, you defined them before the loop.

Comment: I think before learning programming, I should learn English. Thanks. (:

Comment: @OzkanOzlu Don't worry, it is fine. Your english is OK :).

Answer (score 1):

Variables need to be declared before they are used. Depending on your error reporting you will not see the error.

Comment: since its not a fatal error, the code still works, they don't 'need' to be. But I'm a  little pedantic perhaps.

Comment: Error reporting is disabled on both situations. I see the errors on the logs.

Comment: Warnings and Errors are not the same thing